# Magento - Orders with incorrect email address, order confirmations being sent to the web-host

Tags: php, magento

If clients mistype their email addresses when ordering a product, for example a type-o or so, the order confirmation email gets sent to the web-host of the website.

Basically the domain of the email address gets changed to the domain of the host, and the host receives this order confirmation email.

Does anyone know how to change where emails, of which the email address doesn't actually exists, are sent to? Or why/how this is actually happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the return path to where the email should be sent in case if its not delivered
in **System->Configuration->Advanced ->System Mail Sending Settings** .Set  the **set return path** field to **Specified** and specify the email id in the field **Return Path Id**.Hope this helps.